# VSCode: Using nonlocal causes variable type "Never"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-typing, pylance

I'm seeing a strange behaviour of VSCode/Pylance with some Python code. Consider the following minimal example:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from typing import Optional

def main():
    x: Optional[list] = None
    def f():
        nonlocal x
        x = [10]
    f()
    assert isinstance(x, list)
    y: int = x[0] + 3
    assert isinstance(y, int)
    print(y)

main()
```

The call to f() obviously sets the outer `x` to `[10]`. Hovering over `x` in the first `assert` statement (after the function call) shows `(variable) x: None`, which is ok. But after the `assert` statement, hovering over x shows `(variable) x: Never`. This causes both the syntax highlighting and auto completion to fail for `x`on all following lines, as VSCode/Pylance obviously sees a variable that has kind of "no type". Typing `x.` does not even show object's builtin members like `x.__class__` or `x.__doc__`. Assigning `x` to another typed variable does not help. The first assert causes mypy to accept the code, while PyLint says `Value 'x' is unsubscriptable`, so there seems to be some disagreement between other tools as well. This is a bit annoying, as the code otherwise works fine.

Questions: Is this a bug in Pylance? Or even expected behaviour? Is there any way to force Pylance to see the correct type of `x`?

Tool versions:

```
$ code --version
1.56.2
054a9295330880ed74ceaedda236253b4f39a335
x64
$ pylint --version
pylint 2.8.2
astroid 2.5.6
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
$ mypy --version
mypy 0.800
```

VSCode Python: v2021.5.842923320
VSCode Pylance: v2021.5.3

Thank you and best regards,
Philipp

EDIT: Posted the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1355)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the discussion on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1355), I would answer the questions as follows:

- *Is this a bug in Pylance?* Not a bug, but the type inference implemented in Pyright (the type checker of Pylance) does not consider local mutations caused by external execution flows (such as the run of a callback function containing `nonlocal`).
- *Or even expected behaviour?* Yes, at least in part, considering the point above.
- *Is there any way to force Pylance to see the correct type of `x`?* Yes, use `x = cast(list, x)` after `assert isinstance(x, list)`.

With the `cast`, the minimal example would look like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from typing import Optional, cast

def main():
    x: Optional[list] = None
    def f():
        nonlocal x
        x = [10]
    f()
    assert isinstance(x, list)
    x = cast(list, x)
    y: int = x[0] + 3  # Now x is reported as '(variable) x: list'
    assert isinstance(y, int)
    print(y)

main()
```

To summarize the explanations in the GitHub issue a bit more: The line `x: Optional[list] = None` makes `x` of type `None`, as this is what it actually is, no matter how the type is declared. Now, lacking the analysis of the mutation of `x` inside function `f`, the type of `x` is still `None` when the line `assert isinstance(x, list)` is reached. Since the type `None` is no instance of `list`, for the type checker, this line will never pass. To indicate this, the type of `x` is therefore set to `Never`.

Comment: Good explanation! Can you mark it as answer to let others with similar questions know this achievable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Although hovering over `x` shows `(variable) x: Never`, when adding `"debug.inlineValues": true` in **Settings.json** then **Start Debugging**, you could see `x` as a special variable, its attribute `__class__` is indeed `list`:

[image]

When set **Jedi** as language Server, hovering over x is `NoneType` or `list`:

[image]

You could ask in [github/pylance-release](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues) for more help.

Comment: The effect is only related to the static analysis of the code. Running works normally and so the type is of course correctly reported during debugging, as x actually is a list. Thanks for the pointer to the repo, I'll write there.

Comment: Got it. Can you share your github link here for others with similar question to reach?

Comment: Good point, I've updated the question with the link.